# How can I convert the subtitle file format (.rtf to .vtt)?

Tags: file-formats, subtitles, standards-converter

Does anybody knows an easy way to create a .vtt (WEBVTT) subtitle file with an .rtf file? I don't want to have to type all the subtitles new to get the .vtt format!

Is there an easy way to convert it? In example with a software? It's a thing I have to do only a single time so it would be nice to be able to use freeware.

Regards.

P.S.: To give an example. This is the content of the .rtf file:

```
\pard\pardeftab720\ri0\qc
\cf0 Hola, el meu nom \'e9s Marta Peric\'e0s.\
Tinc 22 anys.\
\   
\pard\pardeftab720\ri0
\cf0 0002 00:00:06:05 00:00:08:18 38\
\
\pard\pardeftab720\ri0\qc
\cf0 Visc a Sabadell, \
a prop de Barcelona.\
```

And in the end it should look like this proper .vtt file:

```
0:00:02.26 --> 0:00:05.74
Hi, my name is Marta Pericàs and I'm 22 years old.

0:00:06.40 --> 0:00:08.74
I live in Sabadell, near Barcelona.
```

Comment: I never seen this kind of format you're showing as `.rtf`... There's a [wonderful tool from Uruguay](http://www.uruworks.net/descargas.html), like a decade old (or more) and still on the run, that I always use to subtitle but, for one, it doesn't accept RTF and then there's this issue that your input format is really strange... Oh, **it does have** the WebVTT as output format.

Comment: A good text editor like notepad++ or atom or sublime text might be the tool you need. This looks like a job for regular expressions. https://www.xkcd.com/208/